# Dispatch function in useEffect not updating the state immediately

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, use-effect

In my edit component am trying to fetch my items through dispatch which is not updating the state immediately, i.e i can see state getting rendered 2 times below is the code

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { fetchStream } from "../actions";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import StreamForm from "./StreamForm";

    export default function StreamEdit(props) {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const params = useParams();
      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchStream(params.id));
      }, [dispatch]);
      const state = useSelector((state) => state.streams);
      console.log(state);
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>StreamEdit {`"${state[0]?.title}"`}</h1>
          <StreamForm initialValues={state[0]} />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

**action.js**

```
export const fetchStream = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  const response = await streams.get(`/streams/${id}`);
  dispatch({ type: "FETCH_STREAM", payload: response.data });
};
```

**Entire reducer file**

```
export default function stramReducer(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CREATE_STREAM":
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case "FETCH_STREAMS":
      return [...action.payload];
    case "FETCH_STREAM":
      return [...state.filter((item) => item.id === action.payload.id)];
    case "EDIT_STREAM":
      return state.map((item) =>
        item.id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : item
      );
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

eventhough in my redux devtool am able to see the filtered state(refer attached screenshot)
[redux dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMKVa.png)

useselector hook in the component fetching 2 different state while loading(refer attached)[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SipDd.png)

due to which am not getting the proper state record. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Update your reducer and always return a new copy in reducer:

```
case "FETCH_STREAM":
    return [...state.filter((item) => item.id === action.payload.id)];
```

Comment: And Please share your whole reducer file code if possible

Comment: shared the reducer above and changed also but still getting same issue

Comment: while fetching make loader state initially turn loader on and when its fetched successfully turn loader off then try again because react mounts initially render the component and then useEffect is called so I think you are assuming that your component are rendering 2 times as first time it was on mount and 2nd time when state updates.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why the `console.log` didn't output the updated value.

1. Because your `fetchStream` action creator is an **asynchronous**.
2. Even if `fetchStream` is **synchronous**, it will still not output the updated value, because React itself needs time to re-render. In this case, it has **not** re-rendered the component with updated value yet.

So to wait for React to re-render and get the updated value, you need to use `useEffect`

```
      const streams = useSelector((state) => state.streams);
      useEffect(() => {
        // handle state changes here
        console.log(streams)
      }, [streams]);
```